# Secure rest services based on configurations set in another spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

I am newbie and trying to develop applications using angular with backend support provided using spring boot, spring rest and spring security.

Now, I have the following two queries with respect to securing the rest services.

I already have a working spring boot project configured with spring security using JWT. I have been able to register users, login with the register users etc. I call this project - Identity Services (Project A)

Now I have another spring boot project called TicketingServiceApp where I have few rest services available.

Now I need these rest services to be accessed only by Authenticated users who have already been registered via the IdentityServices application.

So whenever there is an attempt to access any of the rest service in the TicketingServiceApp, it should first check if the user trying to access the rest service is an authenticated user and only then provide access to the rest services.

Now, with this as my requirement.

a) I am not able to understand how to configure the rest services in the TicketingServiceApp to route to IdentityServices application for Authentication.

b) Also, what would be the best way to add the dependency to the IdentityService application in TicketingServiceApp and package both the application?

**For the dependency part, I have done the following and I am able to access the classes in IdentityService application in TicketingServiceApp. But not sure if this the right way**

I have added a reference to the IdentityService in the pom.xml as below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.app.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>IdentityServices</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

However, even with this configuration, when I try a mvn spring-boot:run on the TicketingServiceApp, it only loads the rest services in the TicketingServiceApp. The rest services in IdentityServices do not get loaded even though there is a dependency.

Comment: here lil confused, do you want independent micro services or module based services?